# How do you keep the text from a text box in an appended box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I wanted to achieve is basically adding a text from an input onto something that has just recently been appended. Is it possible? It's basically like a chatting website. The text the user has written is supposed to be kept in the appended object, but I can't achieve it.

Details:- An input where the user types the message.
A button which appends a read-only input.
The read-only input should have the message the user typed in the original input.

Here's my script!

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Friend's Circle</title>
    <style>
        .Hammer-Div {
            background-color: #3a3939;
            color: white;
            height: 100%;
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            transition: 0.4s;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .container {
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .bar1,
        .bar2,
        .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        .change .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }

        .change .bar2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .change .bar3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        }

        .Items {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 30px;
            display: none;
        }

        .Results {
            height: 100%;
            width: 92.5%;
            background-color: #585858;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            float: right;
        }

        .MessageBox {
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            background-color: hsl(0, 1%, 27%);
            border: none;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 1%;
            margin-top: 0.5%;
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .MessageUnit {
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #383838;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        .Message{
            height: 65px;
            width: 40%;
            background-color: #383838;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            border: none;
            margin-left: 1%;
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Menu").click(function () {
                var a = $("#HammerDiv");
                a.css('width', '200px');
                $("p").toggle();
                setTimeout(function () { a.css('width', '80px'); }, 2500);
                setTimeout(function () { $("p").toggle(); }, 2500);
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
                $("#Results").append("<br><input readonly class='Message'><br>");
            });
        });
    </script> </head>

<body bgcolor="#1a1a1a">
    <div class="Hammer-Div" id="HammerDiv">
        <center>
            <div class="container" id="Menu"><br>
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div><br><br>
            <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.PTArRyNau0VomdH647ex3gHaHa?w=183&h=183&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7"
                style="opacity: 0.5; border-radius: 50%; height: 70px; width: 70px;">
            <p>Chat</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="Results" id="Results">
        <center>
            <div class="MessageUnit">
                <input class="MessageBox" placeholder="Type Your Message Here!" id="MessageBox">
                <img src="https://th.bing.com/th?q=Send+Arrow+Icon&w=120&h=120&c=1&rs=1&qlt=90&cb=1&pid=InlineBlock&mkt=en-WW&adlt=moderate&t=1&mw=247"
                    style="border-radius: 50%; width: 60px; height: 60px; border-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 0.5%; cursor: pointer;"
                    border="4px" id="SendMessage">
            </div>
        </center>
    </div> </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach for you to consider:

1. Get the value of text typed in by the user from the `MessageBox` `input`.
2. Create a new `input` tag, make it `readonly` and assign the `value` of new input the value from the `MessageBox` input
3. Append the input to `Results`

```js
$("#SendMessage").click(function () {
   // 1
   const msgBoxIn = document.getElementById('MessageBox');

   // 2
   const text = msgBoxIn.value;
   const newMsgIn = document.createElement('input');
   newMsgIn.setAttribute('readonly', true);

   // 3
   newMsgIn.value = text;
   const resultsDiv = documet.getElementById('Results');
   const br = document.createElement('br');
   resultsDiv.appendChild(br);
   resultsDiv.appendChild(newMsgIn);
});
```

The resulting HTML will be like this:

```html
<div class="Results" id="Results">
        <center>
            <div class="MessageUnit">
                <input class="MessageBox" placeholder="Type Your Message Here!" id="MessageBox">
                <img src="https://th.bing.com/th?q=Send+Arrow+Icon&w=120&h=120&c=1&rs=1&qlt=90&cb=1&pid=InlineBlock&mkt=en-WW&adlt=moderate&t=1&mw=247"
                    style="border-radius: 50%; width: 60px; height: 60px; border-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 0.5%; cursor: pointer;"
                    border="4px" id="SendMessage">
            </div>
        </center>
        <br>
        <input readonly value='Value you added'>
</div>
```

Also notice you used the same name for both `id` and `class` here: `<div class="Results" id="Results">`. Only the CSS declared using `id` will be applied based on CSS selector specificity rules. Consider different names.

Note: the snippet is in plain JS. Consider how you can use jquery for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using it, and it didn't work, but at least I got the reference. Thank you once again!

Comment: What errors did you get? What did not work exactly?

Comment: Not an error exactly, just the value wasn't getting displayed. But I managed to use jquery for it. Anyways thank you for you effort.